# /dev/fd/63 not found on generating csr on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I am working on an online course in which one step is to generate Certificate Signing Request or CSR file for generating a self signed certificate.
The command which should have generated the certificate was

```bsh
sudo openssl req \ 
    -out / root/certreq.csr \
    -key /etc/ssl/private/priv.key \
    -subj "/CN=server.lab" \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:server.lab")) \
    -new
```

However, I am getting the following error on running the above command -

```bsh
error on line -1 of /dev/fd/63  
140520560354976:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bs s _ file. c: 169: fopen( ' /dev/fd/63' , 'rb')
routinesI:B10 new file:no such file:bss file.c: 172:
140520560354976:error:OE078072:configuration file routines:DEF LOAD:no such file :conf def.c: 197:
```

The error output is loosely copied from the VM where I am running the command.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` explicitly closes file descriptors other than 0, 1 and 2:

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/self/fd 5< /dev/null
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:04 0 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:04 1 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:04 2 -> /dev/pts/7
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:04 3 -> /proc/5390/fd
```

So that includes that fd 63 which is the reading end of the pipe created by the process substitution.

Without `sudo`:

```
$ ls -l <(:) /proc/self/fd
lr-x------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Dec  1 08:07 /dev/fd/63 -> 'pipe:[146184]'

/proc/self/fd:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Dec  1 08:07 0 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Dec  1 08:07 1 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Dec  1 08:07 2 -> /dev/pts/7
lr-x------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Dec  1 08:07 3 -> /proc/7305/fd
lr-x------ 1 chazelas chazelas 64 Dec  1 08:07 63 -> 'pipe:[146184]'
```

With `sudo`:

```
$ sudo ls -l <(:) /proc/self/fd
ls: cannot access '/dev/fd/63': No such file or directory
/proc/self/fd:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:07 0 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:07 1 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:07 2 -> /dev/pts/7
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:07 3 -> /proc/7929/fd
```

If `sudoers` allows it (with `closefrom_override`, off by default), you can use `sudo`'s `-C` option to disable it:

```
$ sudo -C65536 ls -l <(:) /proc/self/fd
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:15 /dev/fd/63 -> 'pipe:[148888]'

/proc/self/fd:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:15 0 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:15 1 -> /dev/pts/8
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:15 2 -> /dev/pts/8
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:15 3 -> /proc/15147/fd
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 08:15 63 -> 'pipe:[148888]'
```

(here telling `sudo` not to close fd's below 65536)

Or if using `zsh`, you could use the `=(...)` form of process substitution that uses a temporary file (and passes its path) instead of a pipe (and passing `/dev/fd/<its-fd>`).